# Shorted a charging port; can I just use a different one?

Tags: hardware-failure, charging, usb-c

I have a Thinkpad T480s which has 2 USB-c ports that can be used for charging.

Last night I plugged in my laptop and the port and charging tip started burning and now have burn marks on them. Can I just buy a new charger and use one of my other charging ports? Is that safe?

Comment: Depends if any of the circuitry is discrete or shared & how far down the circuitry you managed to let the magic smoke out.

Comment: The board appears to not have any burn marks; only the port itself. The ports are close to one another. How can I tell if they have shared circuitry?

Comment: You need a circuit diagram - & also a microscope to see what's been fried. Not a job for an amateur, I'm afraid. Take it to a repair shop. You might get lucky & only a single sub-board will need replacing.

Comment: The ports are both on the  motherboard :(

Comment: Does the other port work? Be careful with connecting the same laptop.

Comment: I don't know if the other port still works, I'm not sure yet if I want to try it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You can, but think twice if you should without visitting service first.

**Long answer:**

As mentioned on p.21 of [user manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t480s_ug_en.pdf), second USB-C port is also available for charging. As a rule of thumb, all USB-C ports in a  device should have the same functionality (But in reality not all manufacturers follow these recommendations).

However, after your first port was burned you can't be sure if it was malfunction of charger connector, port connector or somewhere deeper in your laptop.
Port was damaged and it could be caused by shorting on the board, simply this time port was weaker, next time you can have less luck. Also burned port could short circuit and while first try was caused by some dust inside port and was relatively safe, second try will cause bigger damage as current will run throughout device, not just inside port.

**Plugging charger to another port comes with risk to burn it too or cause damage inside laptop, possibly destroying it (ie. killing internal charger or even mainboard)**.
I definitely recommend you to check laptop in computer or electronics service and check port for shortings.

PS: I see that you are looking for a way to diagnose it by yourself. If you want to do this, you need a multimeter and USB-C cable.
Plug cable into socket and check every pin with every pin for shortage. Only pins with the same description can be shorted: https://pinoutguide.com/Slots/usb-type-c_pinout.shtml
If such test don't show shortages, you are pretty safe to plug new charger in. However it's still better to connect a service power supply with current limiter and observe it for anomalies - there still can be some malfunction with more complex element which wont be detected by simple shortage test.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Can you elaborate on using a multimeter to test the port? Or link to a guide on how to do it?

Comment: There's plenty of guides, ie. this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdUK6RPdIrA
Parts you need are resistance and continuity test. Ofc. details may differ depending on multimeter model.

Comment: Do you mean plug in a usb-c cable to the port that has the other ends of the cable exposed, and then use the multimeter on the exposed wires?

Comment: You have to check pins while plugged into laptop port, it's not required to cut cable (you could even check directly on laptop port). But surely it will make things much more comfortable. Anyway you still need at least one small needle to identify which shorted cables belong to pins that can be shorted.

Comment: So plug in the power cord, then use a needle to connect the voltometer to the connections between the port and the board to test?